# Any thoughts on why the Ghost (Electron) Desktop App won't load up?

Tags: software-installation

I'm not sure if this is necessarily an elementary issue or not, but I'm guessing it might somewhat be. I just installed [Ghost's (Electron) Desktop App](https://ghost.org/downloads/) using Eddy (as I've successfully done with other apps) and everything seemed to install fine. However, when I click on the app icon in the dock the icon bounces up, but then nothing happens – no app loads up. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: Could you run the app from the Terminal and check for any error logs?

Comment: @Fultie Okay, after getting around to figuring out how to use the terminal to do as you say (I'm a newbie), I was told `No command 'ghost' found, did you mean:` followed by a list of non-related apps. I did the `apt list --installed` command to check, and yes Ghost is in fact installed: `ghost/now 1.3.0-1 amd64 [installed,local]`. So I'm not sure if there's even any information available to relay to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so, this is an Electon/Ghost bug and it's documented [here](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost-Desktop/issues/274).

Some suggestions are

1. Running Ghost from the terminal using sudo, you can do this by issuing this command:

`sudo /usr/lib/Ghost/Ghost`

2. Changing the permissions for a particular folder which seems to be the origin of the issue, to do this run

`sudo chmod -R +rx /usr/lib/Ghost/resources/app`

The thing is, this didn't work for me. Running Ghost now without priveleges starts it but it comes to a halt after few seconds.

3. Another solution (a very hacky, dirty solution):

If you want to avoid having to run Ghost from the terminal, you could do this:

Install gksu by running

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gksu
```

gksu is a graphical interface that will ask for your password when running a program with admin privileges.

Next, create a .desktop file in the folder .local/share/applications named ghost-desktop.desktop with the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Ghost
Exec=gksu /usr/lib/Ghost/Ghost
Icon=Ghost
Comment=Desktop Client for Ghost
StartupWMClass=ghost-desktop
```

Open a terminal and run

```
chmod +x .local/share/application/ghost-desktop.desktop
```

Now the Ghost icon should show up on slingshot and you will be able to run it by clicking it. (you can also pin it to the dock)[image: Slingshot show new Ghost icon entry]

[image: Password prompt from gksu]

If I you ask me, I would just save myself the effort and just use solution #1.

Comment: Well whad'ya know, it worked, thanks! And FYI, yeah, I'm going to stick with door #1 lest I accidentally do something wonky with the hacky option and accidentally break things. And it's not as if #1 is all that difficult to perform until a more permanent solution comes along.